# Realtime update of batchsize

Tags: function, azure, queue

Looking for a way to change the batchSize of an azure function triggered by a storage queue.

Created a single VM (app service not consumption plan) and set the batchSize in host.json to 1, its processing FIFO messages and managing load perfectly. I am looking for a way to scale this up and down in real time via an api or other method so I can process 2,4 etc messages at the same time. then scale back again.

Is there some supported method to do this without republishing the host.json file?

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a `Consumption plan`, instances of the Azure Functions host are **dynamically added and removed** based on the number of incoming events.

When you're using a App Service plan, you could manually scale out by adding more VM instances, or you can **enable autoscale**. For more information, see [Scale instance count manually or automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/autoscale-get-started?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Ftoc.json).

Go to `your azure function> scale out> enable autosacle` and `add rules` for your demand like below:

[image]